# What does 3 dots actually do here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I saw a react component that has the `state` showed below:

```
class MyComp extends BaseComponent {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          selectedColumns: [],
          params: {
            offset: 0,
            sort_by: {}
          }
        }
        ...
      }
    }
```

Then this react component has a method `getValue` below. Inside this method `allParams` object is created by using spread syntax. I.e. it is spreading methods argument `params`, and after that updates `params` object in components state.

```
getValue(params){
  const allParams = {
    ...this.state.params,
    ...params
  }
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      params: allParams
    }
  })
  ...
}
```

It is then called like below in a child component inside `MyComp`:

```
goNext() {
  const offset =  15 // IT IS NOT JSON, it is a value 15.
  this.props.getValue({
    offset
  })
}
```

I see that `setState` is ok but is `allParams` creation correct? Must not the `params` be an object (json) to be used with `...`? Am i missing something?

In other cases the spread syntax is used like this:

```
const ob1 = {foo: 123}; 
const ob2 = {bar: 234}; 
const merged = {...ob1, ...ob2}; 
console.log(merged) //Output: { foo: 123, bar: 234 }
```

But in my case it would be:

```
const ob1 = {foo: 123}; 
const ob2 = 15; 
const merged = {...ob1, ...ob2}; 
console.log(merged) //Output: { foo: 123}, and ob2 is not assigned!
```

Comment: It is a spread operator. You can read articles online for that to gain more understanding on that.

Comment: "Must not the params be an object" — Both things called `params` **are** objects!

Comment: Please see update, I forgot to show how `getValue` is called later on.

Comment: @user1665355 — And you pass it an object. So that's the problem?

Comment: @Quentin What I wonder is if `const allParams` is created correctly? When we pass plain number in `goNext` method, the `this.props.getValue` will receive a plain number? and `allParams` will not be assigned `...params` ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You said "But in my case it would be" … but it isn't. In the earlier code you are dealing only with objects, not numbers.

Comment: I suspect the problem might be that you think `{offset}` means the same as `offset` when it actually means the same as `{"offset": offset}`

Comment: @Quentin so `  this.props.getValue({
    offset
  })` created `allParams` object that is `          params: {
            offset: 15,
            sort_by: {}
          }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ES6 spread operator can be used on Objects to 'spread' their values into another object to create a clone of that object. It is similar in concept to using `Object.assign`

Sample

```
const x = { a : 1 };
const y = {...x}; // y = {a:1} Equivalent to : const y = Object.assign({},x);
const z = {...x , b: 2} // z = {a:1,b:2} Equivalent to Object.assign({a:1},{b:2})
const w = {...x , a: 2} // w = {a:2} Equivalent to Object.assign({a:1},{a:2})
const p = {a:2, ...x} // p={a:1} Equivalent to using Object.assign({a:2},{a:1})
```

[Handy link explaining this in the context of Redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator)

EDIT: Based on discussion in comments:
In your `goNext` method, when this happens:

```
this.props.getValue({
    offset
})
```

You are actually creating an object like this `{offset:15}`. So when this is used in `getValue` like:

```
const allParams = {
    ...this.state.params,
    ...params
}
```

You are essentially overriding the old offset value with 15 and creating a new object. So essentially, we are *NOT* spreading over `15` but over `{offset:15}`

Comment: yes but see my update with `const merged`, where `obj2` is not assigned to `const merged`.

Comment: please see that `obj2` is not assigned to `merged`

Comment: That is probably because `obj2` is not an object.. It's a plain number. What would be your desired output for that?

Comment: Yes exactly! Plain number. Like `const offset =  15` in `goNext`!

Comment: I understand.. So what would you expect the final object to look like? I'm trying to understand what your expected outcome is...

Comment: I think the idea is to update `params` object in state. like in your link `return { ...state, visibilityFilter: action.filter }` So it would be updated with new offset value

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps